# getting all combinations from dictionary with list values(cartesian products from nested list of dictionaries)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-oscar

I used `django-oscar` and I need to auto-create product variants from one parent product, that has multiple color, size, textile options.

I have the following ProductAttributeValues rows, which I use to populate the auto-created variants.

```py
# Basically, a list of dictionaries with 3 keys: 'value', 'attribute', 'product_class'
[
  OrderedDict([('value', <QuerySet [<AttributeOption: Black>, <AttributeOption: White>]>, <AttributeOption: Red>]>), ('attribute', <ProductAttribute: dress Color>), ('product_class', 'dress')]), 
  OrderedDict([('value', <QuerySet [<AttributeOption: M>, <AttributeOption: S>]>), ('attribute', <ProductAttribute: dress Size>), ('product_class', 'dress')]),
  OrderedDict([('value', <QuerySet [<AttributeOption: Cotton>, <AttributeOption: Wool>, <AttributeOption: Silk>, <AttributeOption: Nylon>]>), ('attribute', <ProductAttribute: dress Textile>), ('product_class', 'dress')]),
]
```

I need to get all combination of the product variants like the following:

```py
# Note product_class is not really needed here.
[
   {
     <ProductAttribute: dress Color>: <AttributeOption: Black>},
     <ProductAttribute: dress Size>: <AttributeOption: S>,
     <ProductAttribute: dress Textile>: <AttributeOption: Cotton>,
   },
   {
     <ProductAttribute: dress Color>: <AttributeOption: Black>},
     <ProductAttribute: dress Size>: <AttributeOption: S>,
     <ProductAttribute: dress Textile>: <AttributeOption: Wool>,
   },
   .... 
   # this list should include all 24 possible combinations 3*2*4 = 24
   # 
]
```

I tried to use `itertools.product` to get the results I wanted, but found no luck. Help needed! Thanks.

---

### Additional question.

Would the following results be a better design?

```py
[
   [
     {  
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Color>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: Black>
     },
     {
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Size>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: S>
     },
     {
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Textile>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: Cotton>
     }
   ],
   [
     {  
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Color>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: Black>
     },
     {
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Size>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: S>
     },
     {
        "attribute": <ProductAttribute: dress Textile>,
        "value": <AttributeOption: Wool>
     }
   ],
   .... 
   # this list should also include all 24 possible combinations 3*2*4 = 24
   # 
]
```

Comment: itertooos.permutations?

Comment: Also, as of 3.6 dicts are sorted by insertion order by default so you could replace ```OrderedDict``` with an ordinary dict.